# How can I access a fixture in a decorator?

Tags: python, pytest, python-decorators, fixtures

I have a fixture, let's call it `myfixture`, being declared using `conftest.py`. I'm trying to streamline a large number of tests to follow the following pattern of using decorators:

```
@pytest.fixture
def myfixture():
    return True


def cleanup(myfixture_value):
    def wrapper(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            if myfixture_value:
                # Run the actual cleanup here
            else:
                # Run another kind of cleanup
        return wrapped
    return wrapper


@cleanup(myfixture)
def test_sample():
    pass
```

In this case, the value of `myfixture` would change the type of `cleanup` that would occur. However, I can't seem to be able to access the fixture or reference it within the decorator. In fact, the line

```
@cleanup(myfixture)
```

shows the following error: `Unresolved reference 'myfixture'`. This works, however, if I add `myfixture` to the `test_sample` parameters since it's being called by the test framework... I don't know if there are other ways of accessing this fixture.

What is the proper way of accessing the fixture value within the decorator?

Comment: `myfixture` is being passed to your `cleanup` function as an argument.  It works just like any other function call.  `cleanup` then returns a function which will take `test_sample` as an argument and return a decorated version of it.

Comment: If you included the definition of `cleanup` it would be easier to make more specific suggestions about what exactly you need to change.  My wild guess is that you defined `cleanup` so that it's ignoring its arguments and that's the thing you need to fix.

Comment: @Samwise good call. I have cleanup defined to use the argument, so that's not the error. I added more clarification to the question, along with a larger code sample.

Comment: @Samwise uhhhh uh-oh you just gave me a _disgusting_ idea, I'm gonna try something.

Comment: It sounds like you do not, in fact, have a fixture called `myfixture`.  The issue isn’t the decorator at all, it’s the module where you’re calling it.

Comment: @Samwise I do have the `myfixture` defined elsewhere in the same module, I'll amend the code sample to show this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this worked. The problem is that the fixture is only really created when `pytest` calls the testing method, which doesn't occur before the decorators are run (AFAICT, I'm not a python expert). The workaround I had is to see if the test function had the fixture provided in its `kwargs` from within the decorator, and act accordingly:

```
def cleanup(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'myfixture' in kwargs and kwargs['myfixture']:
            print(f"CLEANUP with myfixture")
        else:
            print(f"CLEANUP without myfixture")
    return wrapper


@cleanup
def test_sample(myfixture):
    pass
```